# How to save fabric.js rotated coordinates in database and show result with same angle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fabricjs

How to save rotated image and text coordinates to database and print image in same angle? I am trying to save image also text and show in result image.

```
    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/fabricjs/fabric.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fabric Script new -->
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('can');
canvas.on({
    'object:scaling': function(p){
      if (p.target.scaleX < 1)
        p.target._objects[1].scaleX = 1 + (1 -p.target.scaleX )
      else
        p.target._objects[1].scaleX = 1 / (p.target.scaleX)
      if (p.target.scaleY < 1)
        p.target._objects[1].scaleY = 1 + (1 -p.target.scaleY)
      else
        p.target._objects[1].scaleY = 1 / (p.target.scaleY)

      canvas.renderAll()
    },
  });

//canvas.add(profilepic);
var photoCan = new Array(12);
for(var j=0 ; j<12 ; j++) {
  photoCan[j] = photoGroup("User "+ (j+1));
}
var textCan = new Array(12);
for(var j=0 ; j<12 ; j++) {
  textCan[j] = textGroup("Textbox "+ (j+1));
}
function photoGroup (text,x,y,w,h) {
  w = w || 200; //defaults
  h = h || 200;
  x = x || 150;
  y = y || 100;

  var profilepic = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fill: "#000",
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
    stroke: '#fff',
    width: w,
    height: h
  });
  var text = new fabric.Text(text, {
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: "#fff",
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
  });
  var group = new fabric.Group([ profilepic, text ], {
    left: x,
    top: y,
    angle: 0
  });
  group.lockRotation = false;
  group.lockUniScaling = false;
  return group;
}

function textGroup (text,x,y,w,h) {
  w = w || 300; //defaults
  h = h || 200;
  x = x || 150;
  y = y || 100;
  var profilepic = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fill: "#2e2e2e",
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
    stroke: '#fff',
    width: w,
    height: h,
  });
  var text = new fabric.Text(text, {
    fontSize: 30,
    fill: "#fff",
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
  });
  var group1 = new fabric.Group([ profilepic, text ], {
    left: x,
    top: y,
    angle: 0,
    lockUniScaling: false,
  });
  group1.lockRotation = false;
  group1.lockUniScaling= false;

  return group1;
}
</script>
<!-- new script -->
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  //hide add more buttons
  $(".addButtons").hide();
  $(".removeButtons").hide();
  $("#myDropzonef").hide(); 
  //**********************************Important: Show addButtons if already number is specified***********
  //vars to get num of elements
  var photonum = 0;
  var textnum = 0;
  //vars to get MAX
  var phototot = 12;
  var texttot = 12;

  // Add more photos
  $('#addmorephotos').click(function () {
    addPhotoField();
  });
  // Add more Text
  $('#addmoretext').click(function () {
    addTextField();
  });
  // REMOVE BUTTONS
  // Remove last photo
  $("#removelastphoto").click(function () {
    canvas.remove(photoCan[photonum-1]);//remove from canvas
    $('#userphotogrp'+(photonum-1)).remove(); //remove from options
    photonum--; //subtract the number
    if(photonum<=1) $("#removelastphoto").hide(); //remove the button if less than num
  });
  // Remove last Text
  $("#removelasttext").click(function () {
    canvas.remove(textCan[textnum-1]);//remove textarea from canvas
    $('#textgrp'+(textnum-1)).remove(); //remove from options
    textnum--; //subtract the number
    if(textnum<=1) $("#removelasttext").hide(); //remove the button if less than num
  });
  //checked or unchecked photos checkbox
  $('#addPhotosCheck').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked
            addPhotoField();
            $("#addmorephotos").show();
        } else {
          //unchecked
          var returnVal = confirm("This will remove the entered data?");
            $(this).prop("checked", !returnVal);
            if(returnVal) {
              $('#photoslist').html(''); //remove all divs inside list
              $("#addmorephotos").hide();
               $("#removelastphoto").hide(); //remove remove button
              for(var k=0; k<phototot ; k++) {
                canvas.remove(photoCan[k]); //Remove all photos from canvas
              }
              photonum = 0; //reset value of photo number
            }
        }      
    });
  //checked or unchecked BG checkbox
  $('#addBgCheck').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $("#myDropzonef").show();
            $(".morfchoice").show();

        } else {
          $("#myDropzonef").hide(); //*********************************also delete the female files
          $(".morfchoice").hide();
        }      
    });
  //checked or unchecked Text checkbox
  $('#addTextCheck').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //checked
            addTextField();
            $("#addmoretext").show();
        } else {
          //unchecked
          var returnVal = confirm("This will remove the entered data?");
            $(this).prop("checked", !returnVal);
            if(returnVal) {
              $('#textlist').html(''); //remove all divs inside list
              $("#addmoretext").hide();
              $("#removelasttext").hide(); //remove remove button
              for(var k=0; k<texttot ; k++) {
                canvas.remove(textCan[k]); //Remove all photos from canvas
              }
              textnum = 0; //reset value of photo number
            }
        }      
    });


  function addPhotoField(){
    if(photonum<phototot) {
       $('#photoslist').append(`<div class="well"><div class="form-group" id="userphotogrp`+photonum+`" ><hr><h2>`+(photonum+1)+`</h2>
          <label for="userphoto`+photonum+`">Photo type</label>
          <select class="form-control userphotos" id="userphoto`+photonum+`">
            <option>User Photo</option>
            <option>Friend Photo</option>
            <option>Friend Photo (Opposite gender)</option>
          </select>
        </div></div>`);
         canvas.add(photoCan[photonum]); // add photo to canvas
         if(photonum>0) {$("#removelastphoto").show(); }//show the "remove last" button
         photonum++;
     } else {
        alert("You can only add upto "+phototot+ " Photos");
    }
  }
  function addBgField(){
    if(bgnum<bgtot) {
        $('#backgroundlist').append(`<div class="well">
      <div class="form-group" id="bggrp`+bgnum+`" ><hr><h2>`+(bgnum+1)+`</h2>
        <label for="bg`+bgnum+`">Upload an image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="bg`+bgnum+`" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
        <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Prefered resolution is 800x420px</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="userphotos">Show to:</label>
          <select class="form-control userphotos" id="userphotos">
            <option>Common</option>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
          </select>
        </div></div>`);
        if(bgnum>0) $("#removelastbg").show();
        bgnum++;
    } else {
      alert("You can only add upto "+bgtot+ " Backgrounds");
    }
  }
  function addTextField(){
    if(textnum<texttot) {
      $('#textlist').append(`<div class="well">
      <div class="form-group" id="textgrp`+textnum+`" ><hr><h2>`+(textnum+1)+`</h2>
        <label for="text`+textnum+`">Add text line by line</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="text`+textnum+`" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showto`+textnum+`">Show to:</label>
          <select class="form-control userphotos" id="showto`+textnum+`">
            <option>Common</option>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="style`+textnum+`">Text Style:</label>
          <select class="form-control chosen-select" id="style`+textnum+`">
          <?php foreach($styles as $style) {
            echo "<option>$style[0]</option>\n";
          } ?>
          </select>
        </div></div>`);
      $(".chosen-select").chosen(); //change select fields to chosen
      $('.chosen-container').css('width', '100%'); //some bug fix for chosenjs
      canvas.add(textCan[textnum]); // add photo to canvas
      if(textnum>0) $("#removelasttext").show();
      textnum++;
    } else {
      alert("You can only add upto "+texttot+ " TextFields");
    }
  }
 //SUBMIT CODE AJAX
  $("#finalSubmit").click(function () {
      $(".overlay").show(); //show loading
      var formData = new Object();
      formData.slug = slug; //set slug to post variable
      formData.photos = {};
      formData.text = {};
      formData.token = "<?php echo $token; ?>";
      var numofphotos = photonum;
      var numoftext = textnum;
      var phototype = 0; // type of photo -> [user,friend,opp gender friend] => [0,1,2]
      var textshowto = 0; // whom to show the text -> [common, male, female] => [0,1,2]
      var textval = ""; //value of text field
      var textstyle = ""; //value of text style
      var x,y,h,w,str = "";
      //photos
      for(var i =0 ; i < numofphotos ; i++ ) {
        phototype = document.getElementById("userphoto"+i).selectedIndex;
        x = Math.floor(photoCan[i].left);
        y = Math.floor(photoCan[i].top);
        w = Math.floor(photoCan[i].getWidth());
        h = Math.floor(photoCan[i].getHeight());
        str = phototype + "," + x + "," + y + "," + w + "," + h;
        formData.photos[i] = str;
      }
      //text
      for(var i =0 ; i < numoftext ; i++ ) {
        textshowto = document.getElementById("showto"+i).selectedIndex;
        textval = document.getElementById("text"+i).value;
        textval = textval.trim(); //remove leading or trailing whitespaces
        textstyle = $("#style"+i+" option:selected").val();
        x = Math.floor(textCan[i].left);
        y = Math.floor(textCan[i].top);
        w = Math.floor(textCan[i].getWidth());
        h = Math.floor(textCan[i].getHeight());
        str = textstyle + "," + textshowto + "," + x + "," + y + "," + w + "," + h;
        formData.text[i] = {"value" : textval, "prop" : str};
      }
      var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(formData);
      console.log(dataToSend);
      $.ajax({
          url: 'edit-ajax.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data:  {"data" : dataToSend},
          success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
              $(".overlay").hide();
          },
          error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
              console.log( errorThrown );
          }
      });
  });
  //Load from previous
  $(".overlay").show();
  <?php 
  //load pre photos
  $i = 0;
  $prop = Array();
  foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $prop = str_getcsv($photo["prop"]);
    echo "$('#addPhotosCheck').prop('checked', true);";
    echo '$("#addmorephotos").show();';
    echo 'photoCan['.$i.'].top = '.$prop[2].';';
    echo 'photoCan['.$i.'].left = '.$prop[1].';';
    echo 'photoCan['.$i.'].scaleToHeight('.$prop[4].');';
    echo 'photoCan['.$i.'].scaleToWidth('.$prop[3].');';
    echo 'addPhotoField();';
    echo 'document.getElementById("userphoto'.$i.'").selectedIndex = '.$prop[0].";";
    $i++;
  }
  ?>

  <?php
  $i = 0;
  $prop = Array();
  foreach ($text as $txt) {
    $prop = str_getcsv($txt["prop"]);
    echo "$('#addTextCheck').prop('checked', true);";
    echo '$("#addmoretext").show();';
    echo 'textCan['.$i.'].top = '.$prop[3].';';
    echo 'textCan['.$i.'].left = '.$prop[2].';';
    echo "textCan[{$i}].setScaleX({$prop[4]}/textCan[{$i}].getWidth());";
    echo "textCan[{$i}].setScaleY({$prop[5]}/textCan[{$i}].getHeight());";

    echo 'addTextField();';
    echo 'document.getElementById("showto'.$i.'").selectedIndex = '.$prop[1].";";
    echo '$("#style'.$i.'").val("'.$prop[0].'");';
    echo '$(".chosen-select option:contains(Base)").prop("selected","selected");';
    echo '$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");';
    echo '$("#text'.$i.'").text(`'.$txt['data'].'`);';
    $i++;
  }
  ?> 
  canvas.renderAll();
  $(".overlay").hide();//stop loading


}); //document.ready end


</script>
```

> How to save rotated image and text coordinates to database and print
>   image in same angle? I am trying to save image also text and show in
>   result image.

Comment: How about `toJSON()`?

Comment: i used fabric.js to rotate image and text in any size and angle.how to save all in to db

Comment: is there any values assign in order to save image and text angles in database..

Comment: Check this codepen(https://codepen.io/telember/pen/sDjxt) and [doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON)

Comment: evevery thing is working fine like rotation..... but when save and refresh page getting disperssed..... give me your mail send you clear video to you sir....

Comment: VIDEO : http://www69.zippyshare.com/v/mI2EL1ta/file.html CODE FILE:  http://www84.zippyshare.com/v/HUfRVkxJ/file.html
      this is the problem arraising.... you can check the above video link . how to save image rotated angle ....

Comment: You need to use `canvas.toJSON()` it will convert all the data to json. When loading use `canvas.loadFromJSON()` everything will work fine

Comment: in db showing 0,255,78,65,27  like this....

Comment: I will make a demo in js here.

Comment: everything is working ... but in database storing angle is 0,,,,,, how to assign that rotated degree to db. if i rotate angle to 60 and save angle to database once submit

Comment: http://www84.zippyshare.com/v/HUfRVkxJ/file.html

Comment: image and text is saving only on normal.... but not in angle

Comment: In your submit function  remove the loops, instead  all that use `formData.canvasData = canvas.toJSON() ;` then save the data. And while loading use `canvas.loadFromJSON(json)` it will store the data including angle also.. No need to store all those things (left, top, width...)

Comment: this is submit code ,.. can you tell me where can i change sir... http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/Kj9QZJba/file.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `canvas.toJSON()` it will convert all the canvas data to json. Send that data to db. And when loading from db use `canvas.loadFromJSON()`. You no need to store the data from array and load it.

Comment: code file: www84.zippyshare.com/v/HUfRVkxJ/file.html .... any one guys help me how to save this rotated image and text angles in to db..... i tried but angle not saving...the code file also attached..                            
          video: https://video.fhyd6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.3356-2/25493749_1644304915592580_5616184482980857826_n.mp4/video-1513652010.mp4?vabr=313943&oh=1c9664c90254bef957c6d53c2402fa34&oe=5A432898&dl=1

Comment: https://video.fhyd6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.3356-2/25493749_1644304915592580_5616184482980857826_n.mp4/video-1513652010.mp4?vabr=313943&oh=1c9664c90254bef957c6d53c2402fa34&oe=5A432898&dl=1